# batch file. Como ejecutar CMD.exe y darle instrucciones para llegar a una carpeta

Tags: django, cmd

BD

Quiero hacer un script que realice lo siguiente:

1. Abrir `cmd.exe`.
2. Acceder a una carpeta, por ejemplo: `D:\yausmara\WEB\con static\proyecto`.
3. Que ese `cmd.exe`, desde esa ruta, ejecute otro comando.

Gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Debes agregar lo que has intentado, preguntas como: debo hacer este deber no son bien recibidas.

Comment: Tienes toda la razon del mundo. sin embargo, considere que como era una peticion simple y sencilla ahondar en excesos de informacion por mi parte seria contraproducente

Answer (score 1):

Creo que no hay mayor misterio más que esto

/D Es para cambiar el disco si es necesario

```
cd /D "ruta"
call comando.extension
```

Answer (score 0):

Que sucede
primeramente habia leido bibliografia y para hacer lo que yo queria se iniciaba un *.bat con start ..., como por ejemplo

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45400917/start-django-project-by-one-clik-using-bat-file

mi pc actualmente tiene windows 10 64 bit, quizas la confeccion de los batch esta modificada porque sencillamente realice lo siguiente en un archivo `inicio_servidor.bat`:

```
d:

cd \yausmara\web\con static\proyecto

python manage.py runserver
```

y funciono correctamente